# Regex to detect dates separated by newlines

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate text that's in the format of dates separated by newlines.

The date format needs to be in the form of MM-DD-YYYY.

So a sample could be

```
MM-DD-YYYY\n
MM-DD-YYYY\n
MM-DD-YYYY
```

Where there could be an infinite amount of dates entered that are separated by newlines

I've tried `/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\s+$/` but that doesn't seem to fully work.

Note: I want this to allow for any leading, trailing whitespace and empty newlines as well.

Basically,

- A space character
- A carriage return character
- A newline character

I'm not partial to using regexes. If another way is simpler, desired, more efficient, than I'd gladly switch to that. Thanks!

Comment: Use `^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}(?:\n\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})*$/`. Or, `text.split("\n").every(x => /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/.test(x))`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew How can I make your suggestion account for leading and trailing whitespace too? (This is why I tried using `\s` in my post instead of just `\n`

Comment: Does this whitespace include line break chars? Do you allow empty lines?

Comment: @Ivan86 It is clear your solution is not what OP needs. OP needs to validate a multiline string, not extract anything from it. OP should not accept a solution that does not work for them.

Comment: Yes, I [have posted my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61245448/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate a string with multiple date-like strings in it with or without leading/trailing whitespace, allowing empty/blank lines, you may use

**A method to split the text into lines and use `.every()` to test each line against a simple pattern**:

```
text.split("\n").every(x => /^\s*(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s*)?$/.test(x))
```

***NOTE***: This will validate a blank input!

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:` - starts a non-capturing group

  - `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` - two digits, `-`, two digits, `-` and four digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `)?`  - end of the group, repeat 1 or 0 times (it is optional)
- `$` - end of string.

**A single regex for the multiline string**

```
/^\s*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}(?:[^\S\n]*\n\s*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})*\s*$/.test(text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vUhBtO/1).  *This will not validate blank input.*

This regex is long, but is still efficient since the backtracking is minimal (see `[^\S\n]*\n\s*` part where the first `[^\S\n]*` matches any whitespace but a line feed, then `\n` matches a newline (hence, no backtracking here) and then `\s*` matches 0+ whitespace (again, `\n` is not quantified so no backtracking into the pattern is `\s*` fails). The `(?:[^\S\n]*\n\s*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})*` part is a `*` quantified non-capturing group that matches 0 or more occurrences of the quantified pattern sequence.

JS demos:

```js
var matching_text = "\n01-01-2020\n   01-01-2020\n01-01-2020   \n\n\n   01-01-2020   \n";
var non_matching_text = "\n01-01-2020\n   01-01-2020\n01-01-2020   \n\n\n   01-01-2020   \n01201-01-20202020";
var regex_1 = /^\s*(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s*)?$/;
var regex_2 = /^\s*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}(?:[^\S\n]*\n\s*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})*\s*$/;

// Test Solution 1:
console.log(matching_text.split("\n").every(x => regex_1.test(x)));     // => true
console.log(non_matching_text.split("\n").every(x => regex_1.test(x))); // => false

// Test Solution 2:
console.log(regex_2.test(matching_text));     // => true
console.log(regex_2.test(non_matching_text)); // => false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below to **get all matches** that satisfy the regular expression. Notice the parentheses `()` are only around the date part `(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})` so that is what you will end up capturing. Since the global flag `g` is also set on the regex, this will return all occurrences of the parenthesized expression.

Edit: added support for a leading and trailing whitespace.

Edit 2: added `^` and `$` so the regex doesn't allow for more than 2 digits in day and more than 4 digits in year.

Run and test:

```js
let regex = /[\\s]*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})[\\s]*[\\n]*/g;
let dates = " 12-02-2020 \n 09-10-2020\n 03-03-2020 ";

console.log( dates.match(regex) );
```

---

**EDIT:** In order to **validate** the string of dates you could use the `regex.test()` method like this:

```js
let regex = /^\s*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s*$/;
let dateString = " 12-02-2020 \n 09-10-2020\n 03-03-2020 ";

var dates = dateString.split('\n');

var datesValid = () => {
  dates.forEach((el) => {
    if(!regex.test(el))
      return false;
  });
  return true;
};

console.log( datesValid() );
```

Comment: Mostly good, but it's allowing for more than 2 digits for MM and more than 4 digits for the YYYY part.

Please take a look at https://regex101.com/r/fNoKNN/1/tests (The last test should pass but it does not) Thanks

Comment: @user2402616 I edited to add support for what you stated above. Although, I didn't manage to reporduce the more than 2 digits for MM part, did you mean DD? Everything should work now... let me know.

Comment: sorry, yes, I meant DD

Comment: It's working for those two cases now but regressed on my tests for leading/trailing spaces. Please see https://regex101.com/r/fNoKNN/1/tests . At this point I think it's simpler to just use the text.split("\n").every(x => /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/.test(x)) posted above.

I really appreciate all the time and effort though

Comment: @user2402616 I don';t see any regress for leading/trailing spaces. Works perfectly fine for me. Also, the regex you posted in the comment above doesn't work for leading and trailing spaces

Comment: my apologies, run the tests on https://regex101.com/r/fNoKNN/2/tests instead. This includes your updated regex. The middle tests fail

Comment: @user2402616 I'm sorry... It seems that I might not understand what you are trying to achieve. From the link you just sent me it seems to work perfectly!

Comment: @user2402616 from what I understand... the last two assertions given at the link above should fail because they have the format of `{3}-{2}-{4}` and `{2}-{2}-{5}`. All others pass, as they are supposed to.

Comment: Yea, I actually just ended up using the `every` solution. No reason to apologize, I know I probably didn't describe my solution well enough. But I think this post proves one thing I was trying to ask...maybe it's better to just use some cool JS instead of implementing a tricky/hard to read regex :D. Anyways, I really appreciate all the time you put into this. Thanks